# Can type casting mutate variables into the null value?

Tags: java, swing

I am currently reading *Java Programming* by Poornachandra Sarang and have a question regarding the usage of `JList`'s `getSelectedValue()` function in Java Swing.

I noticed that not only is `source.getSelectedValue() != null` (where `source` is a `JList`) checked once, it is checked again after being casted into a String, as seen with `str != null`.

Given this, could it be possible for a cast such as `(String)` to mutate a variable into the `null` value?

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getSource().equals(addButton)) {
        if (source.getSelectedValue() != null) {
            String str = (String) source.getSelectedValue();
            if(str != null) {
                destModel.addElement(str);
                dest.setSelectedIndex(0);
                sourceModel.removeElement(str);
                source.setSelectedIndex(0);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: That second check is redundant.

Comment: What is `source`?

Comment: ```source``` is a ```JList``` populated with a ```DefaultListModel```. After seeing the double null check, I thought the cast to String might exhibit some odd behavior that could make ```source.getSelectedValue()``` null again, hence this example. It seems like @SotiriosDelimanolis clears up that this check is not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible for a cast such as (String) to mutate a variable into the null value?

No.  Absolutely not.  The only way that `(String) someObject` will give you `null` is if the value of `someObject` is *already* `null`.

However ...

It is conceivable that the following *could* assign `null` to `str`.

```
    if (source.getSelectedValue() != null) {
        String str = (String) source.getSelectedValue();
```

In a multi-threaded context (and *in practice* Swing UIs are typically multi-threaded!), another thread could mutate the `source` while this is code is executing so that the first and second call to `getSelectedValue()` return *different* values.  Whether this is an actual problem (and the possible solutions) will depend on the bigger picture.

A partial solution (i.e. to that specific race condition) would be to rewrite that part of the code as follows:

```
    Object selected = source.getSelectedValue();
    if (selected != null) {
        String str = (String) selected;
        // ...
    }
```

However, this doesn't necessarily address other potential race conditions.

Comment: Just as a note: "UIs are typically multi-threaded" is generally true, but OP's question is about Swing which is single-threaded at its core.

Comment: @daniu - What about worker threads / `SwingWorker`?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html.  If the OP is experiencing odd behavior as is implied by this question, then incorrect multi-threading is the most likely cause.  (For example, not using `SwingWorker` or using it incorrectly.)

Comment: Oh you absolutely can weave in multithreading, but you do need to do so explicitly rather than it coming out of the box. I'd just see it as a bit of an advanced usage, and OP's question didn't seem to me like he'd already be playing around with. Since he accepted the answer I guess I was wrong ;)

Answer (score -1):

> Given this, could it be possible for a cast such as (String) to mutate a variable into the null value?

No, once you get that far you can be assured that `source.getSelectedValue()` will never be null.

Also, the 2nd null-check is redundant and can be removed.

Hope that answers your question :)